# Is there a simple way to determine if Protractor is returning a promise?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am hoping for any quick way (hopefully one that I can use in many/all instances) to verify that a selector is returning a promise and not an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hack solution might be something like:

```
var result = something.getSomething(someArgs);

if(result.then){
  // it's a promise.
}else{
  // the usual stuff.
}
```

the right way might be using `instanceof`, I believe protractor promises are of type `webdriver.promise.Promise`( would like some confirmation on this point), a simple checking method might be:

```
function isPromise(obj){
  return obj instanceof webdriver.promise.Promise || webdriver.promise.isPromise(obj);
}

//usage
var result = something.getSomething(someArgs);

if(isPromise(result))){
  // it's a promise.
}else{
  // the usual stuff.
}
```

Comment: Voted for the hack solution, looking for comfirmation of ```instanceof``` solution.

Comment: Cheers! That's definitely pointed me in the right direction. was not aware of `instanceof`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet if you are not sure if something is a promise or not is to use [`promise.when()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=promise.when) to turn it into a promise if it is not already one, and thus you can treat the result as a promise safely.

But most things in protractor seem to return promises that I have seen, so this should be a redundant operation in most cases.

Comment: I am beginning to reallize that I need to wrap my head around promises. new concept for me. I'll be using `promise.when()` undoubtedly. Thanks for the help